# Reading and Printing Weird Things in file Java

Tags: java, file, printing

Well, i'm trying to make an input/output file, so at the start of my application it reads the file and put the information on the right places, and when I'm in the app, i could add info to this file.

The problem is that it reads and writes really weird things like "ï»¿1". This is my Reading function:

```
private Vector<GEPlayer> ReadPlayers() {
    Vector<GEPlayer> play_aux = new Vector<>();
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    try {
        File fread = new File(path + "/bin/Players.txt");
        System.out.println(fread.length());
        if (fread.length() > 3) {
            BufferedReader bread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fread), "ISO-8859-1"));
            String linea;
            int i = 0;

            while ((linea = bread.readLine()) != null) {
                GEPlayer p_aux = new GEPlayer(-1);
                if (linea != null) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            currentidplayer = Integer.parseInt(linea);
                            p_aux.setId_player(currentidplayer);
                            System.out.println("GEModel -- ReadPlayers -- Readed Player ID: " + currentidplayer);
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            currentidteam = Integer.parseInt(linea);
                            p_aux.setId_team(currentidteam);
                            System.out.println("GEModel -- ReadPlayers -- Readed Player Team ID: " + currentidplayer);
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            p_aux.setName(linea);
                            System.out.println("GEModel -- ReadPlayers -- Readed Player Name: " + linea);
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            p_aux.setSurname(linea);
                            System.out.println("GEModel -- ReadPlayers -- Readed Player Surname: " + linea);
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            p_aux.setNacionality(linea);
                            System.out.println("GEModel -- ReadPlayers -- Readed Player Nacionality: " + linea);
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            p_aux.setActualTeam(linea);
                            System.out.println("GEModel -- ReadPlayers -- Readed Player Actual Team: " + linea);
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            p_aux.setBornDate(linea);
                            System.out.println("GEModel -- ReadPlayers -- Readed Player Born Date: " + linea);
                            i++;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            p_aux.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(linea));
                            System.out.println("GEModel -- ReadPlayers -- Readed Player Number: " + linea);
                            play_aux.add(p_aux);
                            i = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i != 0) {
                currentidplayer = 0;
                play_aux.removeAllElements();
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GEModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GEModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return play_aux;
}
```

And this is my Writing Function:

```
private void writePlayer(GEPlayer aux) {
    File fw;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        fw = new File(path + "/bin/Players.txt");          ///< The true will append the new data
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fw);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
        bw.write(aux.getId_player());                           ///< Appends the string to the file
        System.out.println("GEModel -- writePlayer -- Printed: " + aux.getId_player());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(aux.getId_team());                             ///< Appends the string to the file
        System.out.println("GEModel -- writePlayer -- Printed: " + aux.getId_team());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(aux.getName());                                ///< Appends the string to the file
        System.out.println("GEModel -- writePlayer -- Printed: " + aux.getName());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(aux.getSurname());                             ///< Appends the string to the file
        System.out.println("GEModel -- writePlayer -- Printed: " + aux.getSurname());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(aux.getNacionality());                         ///< Appends the string to the file
        System.out.println("GEModel -- writePlayer -- Printed: " + aux.getNacionality());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(aux.getActualTeam());                          ///< Appends the string to the file
        System.out.println("GEModel -- writePlayer -- Printed: " + aux.getActualTeam());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(aux.getBornDate());                            ///< Appends the string to the file
        System.out.println("GEModel -- writePlayer -- Printed: " + aux.getBornDate());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(aux.getNumber());                              ///< Appends the string to the file
        System.out.println("GEModel -- writePlayer -- Printed: " + aux.getNumber());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GEModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GEModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When i execute the program without information in the txt, i can read perfectly all things, it shows the correct information, and tells me that the information is right. But when I restart the app, it throws me an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ï»¿1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at GEModel.GEModel.ReadPlayers(GEModel.java:55) ///< This line is this: "currentidplayer = Integer.parseInt(linea);"
at GEModel.GEModel.<init>(GEModel.java:34)
at GEMain.GEMainClass.main(GEMainClass.java:22)
```

Java Result: 1

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Hint: read about "single layer of abstraction" principle; and maybe about "clean code" in general. Your poor methods are doing way too many things. That makes it hard for you to read your own stuff; and much harder than it ought be for others.

Comment: Start over.  Write one item to a file, and see if you can read that one item.  When you're successful at writing and reading one item, then move on to two items.  Continue this way until you write and read all items.  This way, when you have a problem reading the items that you wrote, the problem is most likely with the most recent item you added to your code.

Comment: add your implementation of `GEPlayer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because when you read you set explicit encoding. But when writing not and the default one is used - usually UTF-8.

Use the same text encoding when writing and when reading (and UTF-8 is would be best choice).

Try with something simple:

```
    File f=new File("/tmp/test.txt");
    try (FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f)){
        int id=1;
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos,"UTF-8"));
        bw.write(String.valueOf(id)); //write player id
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try (FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f)){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8"));
        String idstr=br.readLine();
        System.out.printf("readstr: '%s'\n",idstr);
        int id=Integer.parseInt(idstr);      // parse player id
        System.out.printf("parse id: '%d'\n",id);
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it seems to be happening other thing, because it stills writting weird things...

Comment: There can be an issue - what is returned by `aux.getId_player()`. `bw.write` needs `String`

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work properly but this had resolve some different problems, so thanks!